# Powershell Script lagging on Gitlab CI

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

I am running a powershell script using the posh-ssh package to ssh files from a windows based gitlab CI to a Linux server.

```
 Write-Output "`r`nUploading $($theme.name)..." 
    Set-SCPFolder -ComputerName '141.209.15.16' -Credential $sshCredentials -LocalFolder $theme.fullname -RemoteFolder "/home/cmuwebuser/$($theme.name)" -AcceptKey -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Output "Success"
```

When i run this process in the powershell terminal it runs in under 5 seconds per file but when I run it using the CI script it takes over 1 minute per file.

Answer (score 0):

Added the -NoProgress option to the *Set-SCPFolder* command.  Apparently the gitlab CI terminal view can not handle the dynamic nature of a powershell progress bar and hangs.  Removing all progress bars from the script resolved the issue.